# Difference between ApacheActiveMQ and ApacheActiveMQApollo

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, messagebroker, apollo

What's the difference between Apache ActiveMQ and Apache ActiveMQ Apollo?

Apollo documents says:"ActiveMQ Apollo is a faster, more reliable, easier to maintain messaging broker built from the foundations of the original ActiveMQ. It accomplishes this using a radically different threading and message dispatching architecture.", but there isn't java sample code and good user guide.

Does Anyone use ApacheActiveMQApollo in live environment? Do better performance to original ActiveMQ?

Comment: some info on status of the product in this link - http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/12/apollo-benchmarks

Comment: @Matt Thanks for your response. I also suggest this blog [here](http://hiramchirino.com/blog/) but I want know do anyone used this solution for your live project and get better performance to original ActiveMQ.

Comment: I did a comparision test between activemq and apollow of one of my messaging requirements, not in production though. Apollo did provide a better performance compared to Activemq. About 40% more throughput for persistent messaging. Since my messaging requirements are much higher i am planning to try other frameworks.

Comment: @javausersoma thanks, please write your experience here.

Comment: @MJM, As i said my requirements were to persist large number of messages per second to a single queue. ActiveMQ chokes at the point of persistence after a certian limit. Apollo could persist 40% more messages per second before choking. Looks like Apollo ships with leveldb persistence by default. Apollo does provide a web interface to monitor queues, number of connections, producers etc. Same producer code works for both ActiveMQ and Apollo. I used same numb er of producers for both tests.

Answer (score 12):

ActiveMQ v5 is the current stable ActiveMQ product.  It's well hardened and has a number of features that have been added over the years, it's documented and well supported.  ActiveMQ Apollo is the next generation of ActiveMQ, it's rewritten from scratch using a radically different architecture.  Currently it's not nearly as feature rich as ActiveMQ but it gets better with each release.  There's not nearly the amount of users or support for Apollo currently so you should carefully evaluate it to ensure it meets your needs before choosing it as your messaging provider.